# Unable to open other fragments using android alert dialog fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-dialogfragment

I am using `viewPager` and `fragments` to develop an application . In one screen I use `DialogFragment`to display an alert message .

My DialogFragment code is below,

```
public class ErrorFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.error_fragment, container, false);
        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(350,300);

        Button button=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.yesButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Print -"," Ok");
                if(getActivity()!=null){
                    Log.d("Print -"," Ok2");
                    ((LoginActivity)getActivity()).setCurrentItem(4);
                    Log.d("Print -", " Ok4");
                }
                Log.d("Print -"," Ok3");
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if(isVisibleToUser) {
            Activity a = getActivity();
            if(a != null) a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
    }

}
```

In my button action , I have program to open another fragment however nothing is happening except DialogFragment getting closed.

Below is my layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/button_border">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/errorContent"
        android:id="@+id/errorTextView1"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="36px"
        android:layout_below="@id/errorTextView1"
        android:id="@+id/space4"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_border_2"
        android:id="@+id/yesButton"
        android:text=" Yes "
        android:layout_below="@+id/space4"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_border_2"
        android:id="@+id/noButton"
        android:text=" No "
        android:layout_below="@+id/space4"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="46dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/yesButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="36px"
        android:layout_below="@id/noButton"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I open other fragment by clicking particular button in DialogFragment ?

Even though fragment shifting is not happening the console print inside the button action is getting printed.

Comment: you are getting logs ?? "Print -"," Ok2" and all??

Comment: @janki . Yes I got all .

Comment: put a break point in method `setCurrentItem` and see if your are getting something null. i think your viewPager will be null

Comment: Take interface inside your dialog fragment then implement it inside corresponding activity from where viewpager is being set.  inside that method of activity put your "setCurrentItem" method.

Comment: @MrugeshThaker : I am not clear please explain.

Comment: Can you share code for loginactivity

Comment: rather that putting setcurrentitem inside onclick of dialogfragment, put only interface method inside onlick and then implement interface inside activity.In activity when you implement interface write there setcurrentitem